# how to sum multiple columns into one result from database in php? is that posible?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have big database table and i need result from multiple columns into one. its about how much people is checked from some conturies and every contry has own column. here is some of it:
`rs_turista`, `rs_nocenja`, `agencija_turista`, `agencija_nocenja`, `at_turista`, `at_nocenja`, `be_turista`, `be_nocenja`, `ba_turista`...
they is checking every day. i need to sum it all in php for report. is that posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it in PHP, that's needlessly selecting too much data from a database. All you gotta do is use a `SUM()` and `+` like so:

```
SELECT SUM(column1) + SUM(column2) + SUM(column3) + ... AS total
FROM table
WHERE <filters for a date or other requirements>
```

Comment: that is nice idea. its working but i have 3 pages of different reports. how can i put this  on print page hm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Fetch data using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and then iterate through the diferent keys of the array (each row is an array).

Will be something like this:

```
$conn= mysqli_connect("mydbhost", "my_user", "my_password", "mydatabase");
$result= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT rs_turista, rs_nocenja, agencija_turista, agencija_nocenja, at_turista, at_nocenja, be_turista FROM mytable");

$ttl= 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        $ttl += $value;
     }
}
echo $ttl;
$mysqli_close($conn);
```

Of course, you need to do some error checking on connection, but at last, the basic schema is like this.

Look at here for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: ty i will read it. i test your code and on echo i got number which is in $value = 0; if i put 1 result is 1, if put 982390480 result is 982390480. im little new in php and there is so much code for learn :)

Comment: That's because the query result has no rows.Check that the connection is working and that there's no error in your query.

Comment: i test it connection is ok

Comment: Upppsss... i did a mistake in the original code... I've corrected it

Comment: @Pep Lainez i was change code like your after i first comment... still same.

Comment: Hi, pls., correct parameter orders on 2nd line. First parameter must be the connection and the second parameter must be the query. Also, when developing, turn on error reporting (even notices) on your php.ini . Otherwise find errors will be tricky, like this case.